# Spring Security: authentication userdao is null

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I have set up JSF with Spring Security.

```
I narrowed the problem down to the createCriteria method which returns nothing.
```

Any ideas?

Why does my userdao return null?

I have a MyUserDetailsService:

```
    public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService, Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1864276199817921495L;
private UserDao userDao;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(final String username) 
           throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    bla.bla.bla.model.User user = userDao.getUser(username);

    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(user.getPermissions());

    return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);


}

private User buildUserForAuthentication(bla.bla.bla.model.User user, 
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    return new User(user.getUsername(), 
        user.getPassword(), user.getEnabled(), 
                    true, true, true, authorities);
}

private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<Permission> Permissions) {

    Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();

    // Build user's authorities
    for (Permission permission : Permissions) {
        setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getPermission()));
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> Result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);

    return Result;
}

/*
 * Get the UserDao
 */
public UserDao getUserDao() {
    return userDao;
}

/*
 * Set the userDao
 */
public void setUserDao(UserDao userDao) {
    this.userDao = userDao;
}

}
```

I am able to get the final String username and pass it to userDao.getUser(username) but my method returns null for the user object so that when I access a method I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]     org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFi    lter:226 - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException
```

This is what is called by getuser(username):

```
public GenericDaoImpl(final Class<T> type) {
    super();
    this.type = type;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public T getBySingleValue(String field, Object value){

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    try{
        if(!session.getTransaction().isActive())
            session.beginTransaction();

        //Create a new Criteria instance, for the given entity class
        //Executes a query against a particular persistent class
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(type);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(field, value));
        T object = (T)criteria.uniqueResult();

        return object;
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("ERROR");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } finally {
        if(session.getTransaction().isActive())
            session.getTransaction().commit();
    }       
}
```

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(type); returns null when it shouldn't. No hibernate sql statements are printed out.

My JPA mappings are here:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

private Integer id;
private String username;
private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private String password;
private Set<Permission> permissions = new HashSet<Permission>(0);

/**
 * Default Constructor
 */
public User(){
}

public User(String username, String firstname, 
        String lastname,String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.password = password;
}

public User(String username, String firstname, 
        String lastname,String password, 
        Set<Permission> permissions) {
    this.username = username;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.password = password;
    this.permissions = permissions;
}

/**Get the id
 * @return the id
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

/**Set the id
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**Get the username
 * @return the username
 */
@Column(name="username", unique=true, nullable = false, length=25)
public String getUsername() {
    return this.username;
}

/**Set the username
 * @param username the username to set
 */
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

/**
 * @return the firstname
 */
@Column(name="firstname", nullable = false, length=20)
public String getFirstName() {
    return this.firstname;
}

/**
 * @param firstname the firstname to set
 */
public void setFirstName(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

/**
 * @return the lastname
 */
@Column(name="lastname", nullable = false, length=20)
public String getLastName() {
    return this.lastname;
}

/**
 * @param lastname the lastname to set
 */
public void setLastName(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

/**
 * @return the password
 */
@Column(name="password", nullable = false, length=60)
public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

/**
 * @return the userPermissions
 */
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name="user_permission",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id", nullable=false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="permission_id",nullable=false))
public Set<Permission> getPermissions() {
    return this.permissions;
}

/**
 * @param userPermissions the userPermissions to set
 */
public void setPermissions(Set<Permission> userPermissions) {
    this.permissions = userPermissions;
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name="permission")
public class Permission {

private Integer id;
private String permission;
private String description;
private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>(0);

/**
 * Default constructor
 */
public Permission(){

}

public Permission(String permission, String description,
        Set<User> users) {
    this.permission = permission;
    this.description = description;
    this.users = users;
}

/**
 * @return the id
 */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}
/**
 * @param id the id to set
 */
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
/**
 * @return the permission
 */
@Column(name = "permission", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 50)
public String getPermission() {
    return this.permission;
}
/**
 * @param permission the permission to set
 */
public void setPermission(String permission) {
    this.permission = permission;
}
/**
 * @return the description
 */
@Column(name = "description", length = 150)
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}
/**
 * @param description the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
/**
 * @return the users
 */
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "permissions")
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return this.users;
}
/**
 * @param users the users to set
 */
public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}




}
```

MY userDAO and MyUserServiceDetail is defined in xml file:

```
<bean id="userDao" class="bla.bla.bla.dao.UserDaoImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="myUserDetailsService" 
               class="bla.bla.bla.service.MyUserDetailsService">
    <property name="userDao" ref="userDao" />
</bean>
```

I think my JPA mappings could be wrong...

Comment: Where the userdao is set? If it should be autowiried, you forgot the annotation.

Comment: I define them in my XML and Spring will inject them because I have setter/getter

Comment: What kind of object is type here `Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(type);`?

Comment: It is type genericDaoIml an interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

I added to hibernate session configuration:

```
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
    <list>
        <value>bla.blah.bla.User</value>
        <value>bla.blah.bla.model.UserOrganization</value>
         <value>bla.blah.bla.model.Permission</value>
    </list>
</property>
```